# How do I change the x-axis on my line chart in python?

Tags: python, spyder

Currently I have this code:

```
def graph_s(self):
        ex_list = list()
        time = list()
        if(len(self.sheet) > 1):
            for index, row in self.sheet.iterrows():
                time.append(row['Month']/12 + row['Year'])
                ex_list.append(float(row['grocery']) + float(row['transportation']) + float(row['leisure']) + float(row['utilities']) + float(row['savings']) + float(row['bills']))
            z = sorted(zip(time,ex_list))
            x=[i[0] for i in z]
            y=[i[1] for i in z]
            plt.plot(x, y)
            plt.show()
        else:
            print('Sorry! There is not enough information to create a graph of you spending over time.')
```

However, the x-axis is not the one that I wanted. I want to show the month & year in the x-axis, from oldest to new. When I run the codes it showed me the following graph.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqRlZ.png)
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWzL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `date` object from your `row['Month']` and `row['Year']` by

```py
from datetime import date

(...)
ts = date(row['Year'], row['Month'], 1)  # last value is the day
time.append(ts)
(...)
```

Here is an example of what it could look like when plotting it (see also [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html))

```py
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

y = list(range(6))
x = [date(2021,i,1) for i range(6)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: i tried to change my code with your suggested answer
 (...)
ts = date(row['Year'], row['Month'], 1)  # last value is the day
time.append(ts)
(...)

but now it shows me 
ts = date(row['Year'], row['Month'], 1)  # last value is the day
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: As far as I can see from your screenshot of the sheet, they are integers. So simply casting them to int should fix this: `ts = date(int(row['Year']), int(row['Month']), 1)`

Comment: thank you!!!
another issue that i have with my code now is that for this part of the code:
            x=[i[0] for i in z]
            y=[i[1] for i in z]
            plt.plot(x, y)
when the line chart comes out the x-axis specifies,2021-10-01, making the x axis very messy. is it possible for me to remove the -01 and just leave it as 2021-10

Comment: @user21 I updated my example with the code for the date format. Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped :)